# Minimizing quadratic equation with logarithms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, logarithms, quadratics

I am dealing with an optimization problem of the form: $$x^* = \mathop{\text{argmin}}_{x\in \mathbb{R}^+}\left( x^2 - c_1\log x^2 + r_1(x - c_2)^2\right), $$ where $r_1, c_1, c_2$ are constants.

So could anyone gives some advice of this form? No need to analytic form, numeric solution is also appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method to solve this equation

Comment: $\log (x^2)=2\log x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, but $log x$ still involves logarithm, I could not get your point.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I also think so. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Are the constants all positive ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. I think that is  could a problem to use $\log (x^2)=2\log x$ since $x$ could be negative. Who knows ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The optimization is in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What do you mean by equation? I think this is just about obtaing the global minimizer of $f(x)=x^2-c_1 \log(x^2)+r_1(x-c_2)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $c_1,r_1 \ge 0$ then $f''(x) >0$ and the (unique) root of $f'(x)$ will be a global minimizer. Also, you can compute the roots of $f'(x)$ and pick the one in $\mathbb{R}_+$. So, if $c_1>0$ and $r_1\ge 0$, the answer is
$$
x^* = \dfrac{c_2 r_1 + \sqrt{c_2^2 r_1^2+4 c_1 r_1 + 4 c_1}}{2(1+r_1)}.
$$